# XACML application on SOAP Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, security, soap, xacml3

I'm new to web-services and i would like to know the answer to some questions.

First, i know that **REST** APIS can be consumed just by having the URL of the rest endpoint, on the other side (**SOAP**), you can't consume any distant **SOAP WS** unless you develop a client. Is it correct? And if it is, is it the only difference between the 2 big families ?

Second, i would like to apply **XACML** on some **SOAP** Web Services for security purpose of course. I made a figure that resumes the entire process of XACML.

[image: Req/Response process using XACML figure]

I developed some basic **SOAP** web services with simple 2 methods, and i don't know from where should i start the **XACML** code and configuration. I'm asking you guys for some good and helpful links to apply the **XACML** security filter.

Comment: Which XACML implementation are you using?

Comment: Axiomatics provides a JAX-WS PEP and PDP you can use for this purpose. I can see from your picture you are using Heras-AF. Is this the case?

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. Like i said i'm about to start developing a XACML filter, right now, i'm just understanding the concept. Which implementation you think i should use, and if you can of course, share some useful links about it some java code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example of CXF interceptor doing XACML-based (XACML 3.0) authorization on [Colm O hEigeartaigh's blog](http://coheigea.blogspot.fr/2015/09/authorization-for-web-services-using.html) (Colm is one of the main CXF developers). The actual source code of the CXF Interceptor: [XACML3AuthorizingInterceptor](https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/cxf/cxf-sts-xacml/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/cxf/sts/xacml/authorization/xacml3/XACML3AuthorizingInterceptor.java). It is using OpenAZ as XACML implementation, but you can adapt it to use another XACML implementation, such as Axiomatics mentioned here by David Brossard, or AuthzForce (supporting [embedded](https://github.com/authzforce/core) or [remote RESTful](https://github.com/authzforce/server) PDP modes), or other implementations mentioned at the end of the [XACML TC's page](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml#other).

The first important part of the [CXF Interceptor](https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/cxf/cxf-sts-xacml/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/cxf/sts/xacml/authorization/xacml3/XACML3AuthorizingInterceptor.java) is at the beginning of the `handleMessage(Message message)` method:

```
SecurityContext sc = message.get(SecurityContext.class);
```

The `SecurityContext` gives you information about the authenticated user such as the user roles, which you can use as XACML subject attributes in the XACML request.

The code further creates the XACML Request using the [DefaultXACML3RequestBuilder class](https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/cxf/cxf-sts-xacml/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/cxf/sts/xacml/authorization/xacml3/DefaultXACML3RequestBuilder.java), that extracts other information from the CXF `Message` using [CXFMessageParser](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/rt/security/saml/xacml/CXFMessageParser.html) - that you can find in the [cxf-rt-security-saml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-security-saml/) library - such as the SOAP service name, operation name (as defined in the WSDL), and the endpoint URI:

```
 CXFMessageParser messageParser = new CXFMessageParser(message);
 ...
 String actionToUse = messageParser.getAction(action);
 ...
 QName serviceName = messageParser.getWSDLService();
 QName operationName = messageParser.getWSDLOperation();
 ...
```